# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray' whilst trying to do PCA

Tags: python, csv, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to do PCA on a sparse matrix, but I am encountering an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import csv
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

data_sentiment = []
y = []
data2 = []
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxint)
with open('/Users/jasondou/Google Drive/data/competition_1/speech_vectors.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    n = 0
    for row in reader:
        # sample = row.split(',')
        n += 1
        if n%1000 == 0:
            print n
        data_sentiment.append(row[:25000])

pca = PCA(n_components=3)
pca.fit(data_sentiment)
PCA(copy=True, n_components=3, whiten=False)
print(pca.explained_variance_ratio_) 
y = pca.transform(data_sentiment)
```

The input data is `speech_vector.csv`, which a 2740 * 50000 matrix found [available here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs4786/2015sp/assignments/competition_1.zip)

Here is the full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 45, in <module>
    y = pca.transform(data_sentiment)
  File "/Users/jasondou/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py", line 397, in transform
    X = X - self.mean_
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I do not quite understand what `self.mean_` refers to here.

Comment: It would be useful to know **which** line the error occurs, also your code is in it's current form just nonsense as you're passing an empty list to `pca.fit`

Comment: I'm thinking this happens elsewhere (e.g. in `pca.fit()` or `pca.transform()`); I don't see any subtraction operations that might have raised this error directly in this top-level code.

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to when you say *"did not quite understand what self.mean_ here"*

Comment: Please update the question to include a minimal, complete example that demonstrates the problem (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You haven't shown in the code or stated in the question how `PCA` is imported.

Comment: This is still not a complete example - we don't have access to your CSV file, and we therefore can't know what `data_sentiment` looks like. Could you please add a few rows from `data_sentiment` to your question. Also, please edit your question to contain the **full traceback** for the error message you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not parsing the CSV file correctly. Each `row` that your `reader` returns will be a list of strings, like this:

```
row = ['0.0', '1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0']
```

Your `data_sentiment` will therefore be a list-of-lists-of-**strings**, for example:

```
data_sentiment = [row, row, row]
```

When you pass this directly to `pca.fit()`, it is internally converted to a numpy array, also containing **strings**:

```
X = np.array(data_sentiment)
print(repr(X))
# array([['0.0', '1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0'],
#        ['0.0', '1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0'],
#        ['0.0', '1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0']], 
#       dtype='|S3')
```

numpy has no rule for subtracting an array of strings from another array of strings:

```
X - X
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

This mistake would have been very easy to spot if you had bothered to show us some of the contents of `data_sentiment` in your question, as I asked you to.

---

What you need to do is convert your strings to floats, for example:

```
data_sentiment.append([float(s) for s in row[:25000]])
```

A much easier way would be to use [`np.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to parse the CSV file:

```
data_sentiment = np.loadtxt('/path/to/file.csv', delimiter=',')
```

If you have pandas installed, then [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) will probably be faster than `np.loadtxt` for a large array such as this one.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem then you should accept it (click the tick next to my answer)

Comment: No problem, and welcome to StackOverflow! As a new user of the site, learning [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is the most important skill for you to pick up. Please remember to include as much relevant information as you can in your question. If other users have to ask for important details in the comments then they are likely to get impatient with you, and may downvote or close your question instead of trying to answer it.